# problem with reading jdx files with python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a program that allows me to read and plot the infrared spectrum curves that are on files in .jdx format, but I encounter 2 problems.
the 1st is that the graphs are empty there is no curve that is displayed only the axes.
the 2nd is that I can't read the y axis unit with the command :`plt.ylabel(jcamp_dict['yunits'])`

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mmouss01\Desktop\code_py\Run\plot.py", line 18, in <module>
    plt.ylabel(jcamp_dict['yunits'])
KeyError: 'yunits'
```

Here is the code :

```
import jcamp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from glob import glob
import tqdm

cp = os.getcwd()

for fn in tqdm.tqdm(sorted(glob('Fichier_jdx\*.jdx'))):
    dn = os.path.join(cp,fn)
    
    jcamp_dict = jcamp.jcamp_read(dn)
   
    f1 = plt.figure()
    plt.plot((1/(jcamp_dict['x']))*10000, jcamp_dict['y'])
    plt.xlabel("µm")
    plt.ylabel(jcamp_dict['yunits'])
    plt.grid(ls='--')
    plt.title(fn[12:-4], loc= 'center')
    plt.xlim(3.2, 3.6)
    f1 = plt.savefig(dn[:-4] + ".jpg", dpi=1200)
```

Here is an image of the curve when I remove the plt.ylabel line :
[image]

I did research on the internet but I found nothing and I did not find an alternative to jcamp to do what I want.

Here is a [link](https://uploadnow.io/f/RhXNpGB) to some .jdx files I use.

Comment: There is a KeyError for `'yunits'`, are you sure that is the right key? What does the `jcamp_dict` look like?

Comment: yes according to everything I've seen on the internet, everyone uses this key. I couldn't find any other keys

Comment: Can you verify the contents of `jcamp_dict` using print statements?

Comment: Here is the result after a `print(jcamp_dict)` of one of my files : `{'x': array([], dtype=float64), 'y': array([], dtype=float64)}`

Comment: Well there's your answer. `jcamp_dict` consists of an `x` and `y` field. Use `y` instead of `yunits`. You could have arrived at this solution yourself four days ago with a little debugging.

Comment: I all ready did this befor I posted my problem. The y unit is empty if I do this, for exemple in my jdx fil, there is a line where you can finde "##YUNITS=TRANSMITTANCE". It's this that I whant to appear in my graph. Also there is the problème withe the empty plot even if there are a data in my jdx fil.

Comment: it's finally work, I had just to change :  `jcamp.jcamp_read` to `jcamp.jcamp_readfile`